# How can I Map a substring to a property with a Fluent Nhibernate Mapping Override?

Tags: c#, .net, fluent-nhibernate

I have a string property on a class that I would like mapped to a Substring of another column.

Lets say this is my class:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public virtual string PartNumber { get; set; }

  public virtual string PartNumberPortion { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my MappingOverride:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<MyClass> mapping)
{
   mapping.Map(x => x.PartNumberPortion, "PartNumber").Formula("SUBSTRING(4,20, PartNumber)");
}
```

The .Formula() piece doesn't work like I had hoped.  Is it possible to map a field to a substring of another field?

FYI, I wouldn't need to do this if I could run this query:

```
PartNumber.Substring(3).Contains("12345")
```

Unfortunately, having a Substring in a query results in:

> Cannot use subqueries on a criteria
>   without a projection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully got something like this to work in my solution

```
public override(AutoMapping<MyClass> mapping) 
{
    mapping.Map(x=>x.PartNumberPortion).Formula("SUBSTRING(PartNumber, 4, 20)");
}
```